# Is the amount of RAM in mongodb cluster directly proportional to query response speed

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently using the free-tier which has 512mb or RAM, but I was wandering, if I increase my plan to get 4GB of RAM, will every query run approximately 8x faster? or is that not how it works? Sorry, I know this is noob question, but I don't understand this stuff at all.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database size and ussage(number of queries, number of clients, type of queries etc) , indexes & working set must fit in memory to get good performance, if you have this conditions met already after certain size adding more RAM will add very little benefits...

Comment: I have some queries taking about 10 seconds as they're having to search through thousands of documents, would it help in this case if I increased the RAM?

Comment: it depends on queries, some helpfull questions: 1) what indexes do you use? 2) do you search for whole.documents or just some fields? 3) Is this just find or aggregation queries?

Comment: It's an aggregation query that pulls thousands of objects that are nested within about 100 different documents. The query filters through between 2-10 parameters when checking if each object is a match.

Comment: 10 sec in general is very big execution time, but afcourse without knowing what you do exactly we can't help too much...